VBA - I have a code that looks for blank cells and fills them with the cell from above - end of table get's duplicated 20ish times
I'm looking for help to add/adjust my code to find the last cell and work up.
My code below looks for blank cells and offsets the data below when applicable but I've noticed it adds multiple onto the end of the sheet. Some of my other code has a specification that works from the end up but I can't seem to get them to work together.
Current code that works as intended (till the final line):
Sub Five()

    Dim cell As Range, SearchRange As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set SearchRange = Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not SearchRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In SearchRange

            If cell.Row > 1 Then cell = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value

        Next cell
    End If

End Sub

Lines I've noticed some of my other code has that works from the last row up, which I gather can be somehow worked into my existing code but I'm truly stumped after trying many variations.
Dim LR As Long, i As Long LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row For i = LR To 1 Step -1
EDIT
I tried this:
Sub Five()

Dim cell As Range, SearchRange As Range
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    Set SearchRange = Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not SearchRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In SearchRange

            If cell.Row > 1 Then cell = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value

        Next cell
    End If

End Sub

Removing 'For i' prevented the 20 odd duplicates - still getting 1 at the end.

I am not sure you need the first for loop. Where is the Next that goes with it?  Does this compile?

Removing the "For I" changes it from 20ish dupes to just the 1, is there a way to prevent that final duplicate?

Without For I loop, but change Set SearchRange = Range("A1:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
